# ng2- component property binding not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am working on an Angular 2 app in which I have created a component named `JobComponent`with a property named `candidate_types` and trying to bind the property using attribute binding to `NgbdTypeaheadBasic` component, but it's not working, I don't know why, below are the files.

**job.module.ts**

```
import { NgbdTypeaheadBasic } from './typehead.component';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { JobComponent }   from './job.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ JobComponent, NgbdTypeaheadBasic],
  bootstrap:    [ JobComponent ]
})


export class JobModule { }
```

**job.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
    selector : 'job_block',
    template : "<ngbd-typeahead-basic [options]='candidate_types'></ngbd-typeahead-basic>",
})

export class JobComponent {
    candidate_types:any=['air', 'ocean'];
}
```

**typehead.component.ts**

```
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-typeahead-basic',
  templateUrl: './partials/third-party/typehead.html'
})
export class NgbdTypeaheadBasic {
  public model: any;

  states:any;

  @Input() options:any;

  constructor() { console.log(this.options); }

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : this.states.filter(v => new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(v)).splice(0, 10));
}
```

**typehead.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
```

When I launched the app all the components are getting rendered properly without any error, but I am getting `undefined` for `console.log(this.options);`

I am trying to implement Angular 2 Bootstrap Typehead Component:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead

Reference that I have taken:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Post your error please.

Comment: sorry, I messed it, let me edit the question @StefanSvrkota

Comment: question updated, @StefanSvrkota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because you are trying to print `options` in `constructor` and considering it is `@Input()`, it is not yet passed from parent component at that moment. Implement `OnInit` and print it there, you'll see it will work:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class NgbdTypeaheadBasic implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.options);
}

}
```

You should check out [Angular 2 Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Comment: worked flawlessly thanks, actually I didn't want to `console.log` the values, it was for testing, I am going to assign the option to states property which is also working fine...

Comment: just a quick question, is there a way to pass value from sub-component to parent component???

Comment: @AkshayKhale There is, you have to use `EventEmitter` to achieve that. I suggest reading this article, it is really well explained with simplest examples: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/

Comment: already implemented from the same reference link, but it stops working randomly, not sure what's wrong, thanks again...

Comment: @AkshayKhale Post another question if you encouter any problems.